# Angular, when toggling between two inputs clean request

Tags: angularjs

I have a method that is toggling between two inputs.

```
toggleModToLod(configurableOption) {
      console.log(configurableOption);
      configurableOption.isModField= !configurableOption.isModField;
  }
```

```
<a ng-click="$ctrl.toggleModToLod(configurableOption)" ng-init="">MOD or LOD</a>
<input ng-if="configurableOption.isModField" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.mod" placeholder="MOD">
<input ng-if="!configurableOption.isModField" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.lod" placeholder="LOD">
```

It works fine, but if i had before filled the MOD field and after that i changed to LOD field  the request contain both values, is there any way to have in my request only the selected value from the selected input ?

Comment: Changed the tag to angularJS (which is a completely different animal than angular)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the switch a toggle or checkbox or other form element

```
<label><input type='radio' ng-model="value.which" value='MOD' /> MOD</label>
<label><input type='radio' ng-model="value.which" value='LOD' /> LOD</label>

<input ng-if="value.which=='MOD'" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.mod" placeholder="MOD">
<input ng-if="value.which=='LOD'" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.lod" placeholder="LOD">
```

Then when you send your request, you'll have the `which` variable which will tell you which value to use. Additionally, you'll have a built in switcher that will automatically work by setting `value.which`

Answer (score -1):

just clear both values from model everytime you toggle:

```
toggleModToLod(configurableOption) {
    console.log(configurableOption);
    configurableOption.isModField= !configurableOption.isModField;
    $scope.value.mod = undefined; // however you're setting these on the controller / directive
    $scope.value.lod = undefined;
}
```